# Bind dynamic query to populate GridView or similar asp.net webforms control to display result in a webpage

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a pivoted SQL query that will populate a table:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @yearV varchar(max) = '2019'
DECLARE @idclienteV varchar(max) = 1

select @cols = STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Y].[FechaPpto]) 
                                FROM [dbo].[Ingresos_Ppto] [Y] 
                                WHERE
                                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idclienteV) AND (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @yearV)
                            GROUP BY [Y].[FechaPpto]
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = N'DECLARE @year int = ' + @yearV + ' DECLARE @idc int = ' + @idclienteV + '  SELECT Rubro, ' + @cols + N' FROM 
             (
                SELECT [Y].[Rubro], [Y].[Valor], [Y].[FechaPpto]
                FROM [Ingresos_Ppto] [Y]
                WHERE 
                    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idc)
                    AND
                    (DATEPART(YEAR, [Y].[FechaPpto]) = @year)
            ) X
            PIVOT
            (
                max(Valor)
                FOR FechaPpto in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

The result of this query is:

```
Rubro                      | 2019-01      | 2019-02    
+--------------------------+--------------+-------------
Portal web WP              | 9148489.00   | 9172295.00 
Portal web WP + ecommerce  | 3785304.00   | 9140700.00 
Renting tecnológico        | 7223406.00   | 72986693.00
Branding                   | 3280937.00   | 4912017.00
Mercadeo y publicidad      | 3372619.00   | NULL
```

I need to bind that result into a asp.net (webforms) GridView control or a similar one, so that I can display it in a .aspx webpage.

I can't bind the dates column directly, because that's dynamically populated. How can I bind it?

Comment: You can bind this to a datagrid with no effort. Grid.DataSource = [YourQueryResult]; Grid.DataBind(); This will generate whatever columns it finds in your data source.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange, I was binding it from the front view, thanks to your comment I solved it binding it from the code behind.